# nicematrix and unicode-math compatibility

Tags: unicode-math, nicematrix

I need the `unicode-math` package for `LucidaBrightMathOT` fonts. However, this seems to have some undesirable effects on the `nicematrix` package, eg. brackets and vertical lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceArray}{cc|c}
        1  & 12 & -123 \\
        12 & 0  & 0    \\
        4  & 1  & 2
    \end{bNiceArray}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Left without and right with `unicode-math`.

How can I use `nicematrix` with `unicode-math`?

Comment: Reproducible with `amsmath` `bmatrix` env thus I guess the difference (shorter bracket delimiter) comes from different math fonts (Computer Modern Math vs Latin Modern Math or your Lucida Bright Math).

Comment: I don't see anything specific to nicematrix here? You have changed fonts so characters, including [ and ] have different shapes. You presumably do not want nicematrix to use [ from cmr when  every other [ in your document is using [ from latin modern opentype?

Comment: I was not aware, that this is a general problem. Closing this question in favor of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647491/unicode-math-delimiters

Comment: I am not sure it's a problem, changing font necessarily changes such things, naturally individuals may prefer some fonts to others, but generally best to take the font as a whole, not choose individual characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle At least the vertical line does not match the size of the delimiters, which looks bad.

Comment: You can try to set `\delimiterfactor=1000` for this case (plain TeX sets it to 901).