# unicode-math delimiters

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math, delimiters

I need the `unicode-math` package for `LucidaBrightMathOT` fonts. However, this seems to have some undesirable effects on delimiters.

[image]
[image]

Left without and right with `unicode-math` using the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \left\lbrack%
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
        1  & 12 & -123 \\
        12 & 0  & 0    \\
        4  & 1  & 2
    \end{array}
    \right\rbrack%
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the same delimiter sizes with `unicode-math` as on the left, such that the vertical line mathes in size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX uses two registers f=`\delimiterfactor` and s=`\delimitershortfall`. If v is the height of the material inside it, then the height of the bracket must be

```
z ≥ max(v f /1000, v − s)
```

Plain TeX sets `\delimiterfactor=901` and `\delimitershortfall=5pt`. You can try another setting for your case, for example
`\delimiterfactor=1000`.

Answer (score 5):

With `nicematrix`, you can easily program an environment with bigger brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { MybNiceArray } { }
  { 
    \NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}
    \begin{NiceArray} 
  }
  {
    \CodeAfter
      \SubMatrix[{1-1}{last-last}][extra-height=1ex]
    \end{NiceArray}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A = \begin{bNiceArray}{cc|c}
        1  & 12 & -123 \\
        12 & 0  & 0    \\
        4  & 1  & 2
    \end{bNiceArray} \\
B =  \begin{MybNiceArray}{cc|c}
        1  & 12 & -123 \\
        12 & 0  & 0    \\
        4  & 1  & 2
    \end{MybNiceArray}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here the solution I will continue with, which uses `nicematrix`, but makes the vertical line smaller:

```
% augmented matrix
\usepackage{mathtools, nicematrix, tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand{\augmentedline}{}{\CodeAfter\tikz\draw ([yshift=-1mm]1 -| \arabic{jCol}) -- ([yshift=1mm]last -| \arabic{jCol});}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{bmata}{}
  {\begin{bNiceMatrix}}
  {\augmentedline\end{bNiceMatrix}}%
```