# nicematrix: add ttfamily in the last-col

Tags: amsmath, nicematrix

How can I get `nicematrix` to put the last annotation-column in `\footnotsize` and `\ttfamily` for me?

Note: I usually use symbols `+, -, ·` and Roman numerals (`I, II, III,...`) there. 
So there is no  mandatory reason to keep the math mode here.

So a possible result could look like this:

[image]

**My MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c c c   |   c}[
last-col,
%code-for-last-col = ???,
]
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & II + 2\mathord{\cdot} I - III  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 &
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

By the way: I would like to have `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` brackets here (instead of braces '[ ]'); I know about `NiceArrayWithDelims` from the manual; but this does not like me with the other stuff for my first try. Is there an easy way, to use group-brackets here?

Comment: @JasperHabicht  No, no: explicit the group brackets, that means "rounded square brackets" (but my main problem is the 'ttfamily' right now)

Comment: I have the feeling that math mode and `\ttfamily` don't really work together ... Could you elaborate a bit on what this annotation is supposed to mean?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I added a picture. Maybe now it is clear, what I want to creat with nicematrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.16) provides the ability to put directly the delimiters `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` (via `\left\lbroup` and `\right\rgroup`) in the preamble of an environment such as `{NiceArray}`.

With that new version, you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}

$\begin{NiceArray}{\left\lgroup ccc|c\right\rgroup L}
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & II + 2I - III  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 5 &
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

---

Sorry, but it's not possible to do that with the current version of `nicematrix` (6.15).

If you want, here is a workaround. I don't use the key `last-col` but I add the column explicitly in the preamble of the array and position the parenthesis in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}

$\begin{NiceArray}{(ccc|c)L}
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & II + 2I - III  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 5 &
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

It's not possible to put in the preamble the delimiters `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` but here is a trick by putting `\{` and `\}` redefined previously...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\ttfamily\footnotesize}l<{$}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyNiceArray}{}
  {%
    \let \{ \lgroup 
    \let \} \rgroup
    \begin{NiceArray}%
  }
  {\end{NiceArray}}

$\begin{MyNiceArray}{\{ccc|c\}L}
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & II + 2I - III  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 5 &
\end{MyNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Ah, I understand. Super! In any case, recently one of my favorite packages. ;)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that you can actually place the delimiters inside the column type declaration! Sure, this is of course then a nice way to solve this! What would be a great addition to the package is that you can somewhere define the column type for the `first-col` and `last-col`, maybe with another option such as `first-col-type` and `last-col-type`. This would simplify things, I guess.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht: Yes. It's a good idea to create `first-col-type` and `last-col-type`...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would probably be a solution, but since the contents of the nodes is in math mode by default and hence `\ttfamily` cannot be used, you need to place your annotation in a `\texttt` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArrayWithDelims}{\lgroup}{\rgroup}{ c c c | c }[
    last-col,
    code-for-last-col={\footnotesize}
]
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & \texttt{II + 2\cdot I - III} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 &
\end{NiceArrayWithDelims}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as I know, the `nicematrix` does not provide some way to enclose the contents in the last column by some macro, you can only prepend macros using `code-for-last-col`, but this does not help much here. Also, you cannot go the other way around and only let the relevant columns be typeset in math mode, because the `NiceArrayWithDelims` environment needs to be in math mode completely.

---

If you wish to make the delimiters a bit larger, you can use a nested `\SubMatrix` which provides the option `extra-height` (this solution has been proposed by the package author for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647533/47927)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ MybNiceArray } { } { 
    \NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}
    \begin{NiceArray} 
} {
    \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix\lgroup{1-1}{last-last}\rgroup[extra-height=1ex]
    \end{NiceArray}
}

\begin{document}

$\begin{MybNiceArray}{ c c c | c }[
    last-col,
    code-for-last-col={\footnotesize}
]
1 & -2 & 3 & 5 & \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & \texttt{II + 2\cdot I - III} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 3 &
\end{MybNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes sure.But I asked myself, whether one set this globally. As a special column, so to speak. Of course, brute force usually works.

Comment: @cis It is difficult to exclude a column from math mode inside a matrix that is completely in math mode. I am not sure whether this can work. I will continue to look for a solution.

Comment: @cis Sadly, there seems to be no way really. `code-for-last-col` only puts some code before the contents of that cell, but you cannot wrap the contents. I currently cannot think of another way to handle this the way you'd like to.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Maybe our author, Mr. @F. Pantigny, has an idea. ;)